# Excel VBA syntax error and using other methods other than select

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code that is supposed to format a tab of information. I took it from a piece of code previously used and I am modifying it to fit my needs. I am getting a `syntax error` on the `.Selection Subtotal   GroupBy:=3, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(8, 10), _
        Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True` line.

VBA isn't exactly a strong point of mine so I would like to figure out a way to perform this properly. I know selection is frowned upon so if anyone has a way around it without me having to redo a bunch of code that would be awesome.

```
With ActiveSheet
.Range("A10").Select
.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
.Selection Subtotal GroupBy:=3, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(8, 10), _
    Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2

.Range("C8").Select
End With
```

Comment: Doing this by head (and from ancient memory). But that "subtotal" seems really out of place? Shouldn't there be at least a comma behind it?

Comment: Further reading on avoiding select: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code should be:

```
With ActiveSheet
.Range("A10").Select
.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=3, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(8, 10), _
    Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2

.Range("C8").Select
End With
```

`Subtotal` is a sub that needs to be called on the `Selection`.  Therefore it needs a period between the two to make the call.

Also `Selection` is not a property of the `ActiveSheet` so the preceding period should be dropped inside the `With` block.

Comment: When doing that I receive a `object doesn't support this property or method` error, and still highlights the same line of code the syntax error popped up at.

Comment: I also missed that `Selection` should not have a `.` in front of it.  It is not a property of the `ActiveSheet` so it belongs outside the scope of the `With`.  See edit.